# I write the right subject but the site don't accept it

Tags: .htaccess

How can i rewrite this in .htaccess correctly?

So I have a query string in my url:

```
/index.php?page=pageCount&subject=mySubject
```

I want to change it to:

```
/index/pageCount/mySubject
```

and also

```
/show.php?subject=mySubject
```

to

```
/mySubject
```

and also

```
search.php?key=myKey
```

to

```
/key/myKey
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&subject=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^key/([^/]+)$ search.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ show.php?subject=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks but in the mySubject if it has dot (.) in it, it will not show

Comment: Updated answer, try it again.